# ORA-00001: unique constraint (SQL_IMGMWWSYJIADSBASGSEZBXHAN.COUNTRY_C_ID_PK) violated ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL",

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

So i was using Oracle Live SQL and encountered a error message that says:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint
>   (SQL_IMGMWWSYJIADSBASGSEZBXHAN.COUNTRY_C_ID_PK) violated ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1707

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES 
    ( 142
    , 'Curtis'
    , 'Davies'
    , 'CDAVIES'
    , '650.121.2994'
    , TO_DATE('29-JAN-1997', 'dd-MON-yyyy')
    , 'ST_CLERK'
    , 3100
    , NULL
    , 124
    , 50 
    );
```

The ,50 (2nd to the last line) is the line 1707 of code. How to fix this/solve this error?

Comment: can you write your table structure?

Comment: could be that you don't allow NULL value in the column related ..

Comment: The error message tells you which unique constraint has been violated. You must not insert duplicate value into that column.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks man :D i just re-run all the script/code that's why in first run it does not prompt that error and when i re-run the script again it showed the error... bottom line: do not re-run all codes because it will cause a duplication error :D

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You are inserting values for the primary key of the table that are already there. How to fix that? Do not insert duplicate values for the PK.

Comment: What are the columns you want to insert to? Is the value 142 the primary key of the record?
If so, than you know where your problem is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message says the unique constraint has been violate

it means one of columns which you want to insert it duplicate value , should be unique value.

So you can check it , if there is duplicate values